# Firestore rules to allow write on two separate Uids

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[image][image]I am writing a chat application and am done apart from the security rules section. I am currently creating two documents for each message (one each for each user) I am okay with writing a document to my user Id but the database isn't allowing for a write in the other paired user Id.

I have tried by allowing the write if the userId is in the resource.data of the other file

```
match /message/{user}/{chatRoomID}/{messageId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user || request.auth.uid in resource.data;
}
```

How can I make it so whenever a message is sent to the database it is only read and can be written by the specific user Ids??
Each message object has reference to who sent it (each user's object Id). Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal, complete/standalone code that writes the message and gets rejected. It'd also be useful to see a screenshot of a sample document.

Comment: This `request.auth.uid in resource.data` clause seems very unlikely to be correct. More likely you'll need to include the field that contains the other user's UID, and use `==` for the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

While `in` is indeed an operator in security rules, this won't work:

```
request.auth.uid in resource.data
```

The `in` operator checks if a **key** exists in a map, where it is much more likely that you store the UID of the other user in the **value** of a field.

To check whether a certain field has a specific value, use something like this:

```
request.auth.uid == resource.data.senderID
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. is it because the senderId file isn't in the direct path? Should I instead write resource.data.chaRoomId.MessageId.senderId??

Comment: The security rules need to match however you store the sender's UID in your document. That depends on your document structure, which is why I asked you to add code/screenshot to your question.

Comment: Thanks. Aside from the field name (which I just updated in my answer to match your screenshot), this should work. If it doesn't, update your question to also provide the [minimal, complete/standalone code that writes the message and gets rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried various possibilities but this still doesn't work. I need to not only to be able to post the message to /message/myUID but also to /message/myBoundUID so the above code won't work ultimately. What can I do??

Comment: Edit your question to include the **code** that reproduces the problem. See [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285981/firestore-rules-to-allow-write-on-two-separate-uids/58286845?noredirect=1#comment102938285_58285981), and [my second comment under my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285981/firestore-rules-to-allow-write-on-two-separate-uids/58286845?noredirect=1#comment102945600_58286845).